# In kotlin QR Code scan from image which is picking from the gallery, working fine via camera but not with gallery image?

Tags: android, kotlin, qr-code

In kotlin, It is a good response, when we capture image from camera, but if i want to scan qr code from image which we are selecting from gallery, it does not work. i apply the same code, with same  logic i  implemented in camera capturing image code. Select image from gallery does not work.  Please help me.  Thank you in advance.

the code is, which i am implementing when i got imagepath of gallery.
It always goes to exception part because it does not load the image.

```
if (requestCode == IDEA_ATTACHMENTS && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {


                val mediaScanIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE)
                mediaScanIntent.data = imagePath
                launchMediaScanIntent(mediaScanIntent)
                try {
                    val bitmap = decodeBitmapUri(this, imagePath)
                    if (detector!!.isOperational && bitmap != null) {
                        val frame = Frame.Builder().setBitmap(bitmap).build()
                        val barcodes = detector!!.detect(frame)
                        for (index in 0 until barcodes.size()) {
                            val code = barcodes.valueAt(index)
                            scanResults!!.text = scanResults!!.text.toString() + code.displayValue
                            System.out.println("Satyendra=scanresult"+scanResults!!.text)
                            Toast.makeText(this, scanResults!!.text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                            val type = barcodes.valueAt(index).valueFormat

                            when (type) {
                                Barcode.CONTACT_INFO -> Log.i(LOG_TAG, code.contactInfo.title)
                                Barcode.EMAIL -> Log.i(LOG_TAG, code.email.address)
                                Barcode.ISBN -> Log.i(LOG_TAG, code.rawValue)
                                Barcode.PHONE -> Log.i(LOG_TAG, code.phone.number)
                                Barcode.PRODUCT -> Log.i(LOG_TAG, code.rawValue)
                                Barcode.SMS -> Log.i(LOG_TAG, code.sms.message)
                                Barcode.TEXT -> Log.i(LOG_TAG, code.rawValue)
                                Barcode.URL -> Log.i(LOG_TAG, "url: " + code.url.url)
                                Barcode.WIFI -> Log.i(LOG_TAG, code.wifi.ssid)
                                Barcode.GEO -> Log.i(LOG_TAG, code.geoPoint.lat.toString() + ":" + code.geoPoint.lng)
                                Barcode.CALENDAR_EVENT -> Log.i(LOG_TAG, code.calendarEvent.description)
                                Barcode.DRIVER_LICENSE -> Log.i(LOG_TAG, code.driverLicense.licenseNumber)
                                else -> Log.i(LOG_TAG, code.rawValue)
                            }
                        }
                        if (barcodes.size() == 0) {
                            scanResults!!.text = "Scan Failed "
                        }
                    } else {
                        scanResults!!.text = "Could not set up the Barcode detector!"
                    }
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to load Image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show()
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString())
                }
```

Comment: Welcome Satyendra. What's the exception when you reach the catch?

Comment: First of all. pablobu thanx for your response,
"Failed to load image" message i got, when i am select the image from gallery and it direct goes to exception block.

Comment: Actually, i want to implement the qr code application in kotlin, by both method, camera and by selecting image from gallery and scan it , i succeded in the camera      part but i got error in gallery image selection, it directly goes to exception block.